# Disable Google+ and enable only Gmail functionality

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-plus

Is it possible to disable Google+ and only enable Gmail features basically includes email and chat only functions? Certain instances may cause Google+ as a mere distraction, knowing that by default Google's embedding G+ links and notifications to Gmail. This may trigger the attention of a user particularly an employee who's in the middle of work to check their Google+ status and updates and get distracted most probably 10 -15 minutes, and worst if he/she lets the time flies.

Consider the case:
  You're opening you're gmail to check an important reply from your boss or from your client.
You're beginning to read your emails and suddenly, "the bell rings" - new gmail notification alert! The moment you start clicking that bait, you probably indulge yourself in Google+ and forgetting everything important that needs to be accomplished that day.

This is applicable to a "Gmail-centered" company, be it a starter company or a medium scale businesses.

I'm out of grammar, hopefully, this is clear enough.

Comment: Can you please update the question to clarify - is this for a personal account (ie - with gmail.com) or is this a Google Apps account (ie - a company address that is using Google services)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still haven't answered the fundamental question in the previous comment: Is this for a Google Apps account or just for just for a personal account? The answers will be fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete your Google+ profile via your account settings on the page. They can be separate.

Many people in my office use Gmail but very few use Google+.

Also, it seems that now you are not required to set up a Google+ account when registering for Gmail

http://gizmodo.com/gmail-no-longer-forces-new-users-to-make-a-google-acco-1637144049

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible and disabling Google+ does not affect Gmail service at all. You just need to delete your Google+ profile.
Please visit [official help page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1044503?p=downgrade&rd=1) for step by step instructions on how to disable Google+ profile.